# How to sort an array of String that has combinations of decimals and alphabets?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array like below.

```
String [] arr = [ "0.1 IN", "0.2 IN", "1.4 IN" , "1.04 IN", "2.4 IN" , "0.01 IN", "11.4 IN" ];
```

How can I sort this kind of array ? Kindly suggest me a solution

Comment: The question is how do YOU want to sort it? Then, we can see how this can be achieved.

Comment: Create your own datatype, implement the sorting you want to apply, and use that Type instead of String.

Comment: You have to implement your own sorting

Comment: Did you try `Arrays.sort(arr);`? The `Arrays` class also has [a method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) which accepts your own `Comparator`.

Comment: A custom `Comparator` is another possible solution.  However, don't expect us to code this for you, or provide you with an "example".  StackOverflow is not a "do my programming for free" service.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how exactly you want your elements should be sorted. Like do you want the string elements first or the decimals first? Also it would be helpful for others if you show us any sample code which you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `sort` method in `Arrays` that takes a comparator:

```
static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

You could define your own `Comparator` like this:

```
Comparator<String> compareLengths = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String left, String right) {
        ... parse the strings to come up with some kind of number
        ... return -1 if the left number < the right number, 0 if the
        ... left number = the right number, 1 if the left number > the
        ... right number
    }
}
```

and use `compareLengths` as the second argument to `sort`.

If you could be sorting a large number of strings, this is not the most efficient way to do it, because you'll be parsing the same strings multiple times.  So if the amount of data could be large, you're better off defining a new type that implements `Comparable`:

```
class Length implements Comparable<Length> {
    private double length;  // in inches, or whatever common unit you choose
    private String lengthString;
    public Length(String lengthString) {
        this.lengthString = lengthString;
        this.length = // parse the string and come up with a number
    }
    // getters
    @Override
    public compareTo(Length other) {
        return Double.compare(this.length, other.length);
    }
}
```

Create a new `Length[]` by constructing a new `Length` from each element in your `String[]`, and sort that.

**Note:** not tested, and I could have gotten some details wrong...

**Note 2:** I'm assuming that the strings in your question are length measurements, and that you want to compare them as if comparing actual numeric values.  But if you were looking for some other kind of comparison, either of the above two solutions should still work if you adapt it to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for sort your array values according to the decimal values.

```
public class Test
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

   String[] arr = { "0.1 IN", "0.2 IN", "1.4 IN", "1.04 IN", "2.4 IN",  "0.01 IN", "11.4 IN" };

ArrayList<SortHelper> list = new ArrayList<SortHelper>();

//separate numbers and words
for (String value : arr)
{
  SortHelper sh = new SortHelper();
  sh.setNumer(Double.valueOf((value.split(" "))[0]));
  sh.setWord((value.split(" "))[0]);

  list.add(sh);

}

//compare according to decimal value
Collections.sort(list);

}

/**
 * Helper class for sorting the string values in your array.
 *
 */
public static class SortHelper implements Comparable
{

private double numer;

private String word;

public SortHelper()
{

}

public double getNumer()
{
  return numer;
}

public void setNumer(double numer)
{
  this.numer = numer;
}

public String getWord()
{
  return word;
}

public void setWord(String word)
{
  this.word = word;
}

/**
 * compare according to your string value decimal number.
 */
@Override
public int compareTo(Object obj)
{
  SortHelper sh = (SortHelper) obj;

  if (this.getNumer() == sh.getNumer())
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else if (this.getNumer() > sh.getNumer())
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return -1;
  }
}

}

}
```